# If a question is deleted do the negative votes go away and your points restored?

Tags: support, questions

Just wondering if negative votes go away and your lost points restored on deleted questions.

Comment: Fun fact: If you're worried about the post ban, you can request the post to be [removed from your account entirely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-ccwiki), owing to a rule of the cc:wiki license. Though overdoing this might lead to the devs stepping on your toes instead because they're the ones who have to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all reputation gains and losses from deleted questions are canceled — unless a post is scored high enough and is old enough, but that's not your case.

However: **overdo this and [the site will eventually stop accepting questions and/or answers from you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers/86998#86998)**, so tread very carefully.

Comment: Thanks for the help.